# Stop Update the update_by field of user table while Login in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, authentication, model, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I have the following code inside my User model.

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if ($user = Auth::user()) {
                $model->created_by = $user->id;
                $model->modified_by = $user->id;
            }
        });
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            if ($user = Auth::user()) {
                $model->modified_by = $user->id;
            }
        });
    }
```

On login, as the remember_token is updated in the user table, the updated_by is also updated.
is there any way to stop updating on special occasions like login ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the updating event you can check, if the current value of remember_token is same as old one (with `getOriginal` method). And only then update also modified_by.

```
static::updating(function ($model) {
    if ($user = Auth::user()) {
        if ($model->remember_token == $model->getOriginal('remember_token')) {
            $model->modified_by = $user->id;
        }
    }
});
```